# disable and enable click after toggleClass

Tags: jquery

i'm using a hamburger menu icon which transforms on click.

The animation is being doing via .toggleClass

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-hamburger-big').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ampnuwsd/8/

This icon triggers an basic bootstrap menu. However i've noticed that the animation hangs when you click it if the page is still loading or when you click it a second time really fast. It will still trigger the menu to pop open however the transform just skips which results in a reversed icon ( an X when the menu is closed and a hamburger when the menu is open )

Is there any way to delay to ability to click, for let's say 1,5 seconds, after the first click has been done?

Edit: Scrolling script:

```
<script>
// script for smooth scrolling to anchor points
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 901, 'swing', function() {

    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily disable the button until the transition end with a promise or by not toggling the class when `.is(':animated')`

Or more simply :

```
$('#nav-hamburger-big').click(function() {
    $('#menu').is(':hidden') ? $(this).removeClass('open') : $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

EDIT:

Based on the fiddle:

1. You need to change the button to have the id nav-hamburger-big
2. change your first css line to #nav-hamburger-big div {

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    //disable the button first
    $('#nav-hamburger-big').prop('disabled',true);
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 901, 'swing', function() {
      //now re-enable
      $('#nav-hamburger-big').prop('disabled',false);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, however, this does not seem to solve the problem. When i refresh and click the button real quick it still buggs out.

Comment: see edit - rather than testing for whether $(this).hasClass() you need to test for if the menu is hidden or not

Comment: Sad to say it's still buggy. The site uses an smooth scrolling script. When I open the menu on the top of the page, click the menu item that is at the bottom of the page it will scroll smoothly to the bottom. It seems like it's the most buggy while scrolling. If i click the button while the page is scrolling to the buttom it bugs 7 out of 10 times. So disabling the whole click for 1 to 2 second after it has been clicked, or while the page is scrolling seems like the most logical fix?

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like we need to see more of your menu code to determine what's up. I don't think I'd recommend adding a disable for several seconds. Probably better to simplify all the movement and animations instead... You could disable while scrolling but you'd need to use the smooth scrolling script's event handlers. What are you using?

Comment: See my edit in original post for the scrolling script.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't show us what's going on in scroll... I see no problem with the fiddle you posted, works fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80311/discussion-between-psalmody-and-arjen).